# Implement IF statement in SQL query in Laravel5 eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use this query into my laravel application, but I don't know how to write the IF part!

```
SELECT    
`users`.* ,    
IF(`friends`.`user_id` = '2' , TRUE , FALSE) AS `user_friend`         
FROM `users`    
LEFT JOIN `friends` ON `friends`.`friend_id` = `users`.`id`  AND `friends`.`user_id` = '2'    
WHERE `users`.`id` != '2'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DB::raw`.

```
User::select(DB::raw('users.* , IF(friends.user_id = '2' , TRUE , FALSE) AS user_friend'))
->join('friends', 'friends.friend_id', '=', 'user.user_id')
->where('friends.user_id, 2)
->where('user.id', '!=', 2);
```

Updated:

You can have a look at [Advanced Join Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins)

```
->join('friends', function ($join) {
        $join->on('friends', 'friends.friend_id', '=', 'user.user_id')
             ->where('friends.user_id', 2);


    })
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! I have 2 conditions in my letfjoin.. how can I write my both conditions?

Comment: You can actually put it in the where statement after the joins, code updated.

Comment: The condition should be in the leftjoin , it doesn't show the right result when I place it in where

Answer (score 1):

Try below full query:

```
User::select(DB::raw("users.* , IF(friends.user_id = '2' , TRUE , FALSE) AS user_friend"))  
->join('friends', function ($join) {  
  $join->on('friends', 'friends.friend_id', '=', 'user.user_id')  
  ->where('friends.user_id', 2);  
});
```

This is the version after correction from @SteD answer. Hope this work for you!